# Swift 5 Alamofire dictionary parsing error

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, alamofire, swift5

I want to parse json with Alamofire , in Swift 5 but I didnt get array my codes under below.

My json file

```
[{"type":"success","data":[{"id":"1","sectionId":"1","title":"test title","detail":"detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text detail test text ","image":"test.jpg","view":"0","status":"1"}]}]
```

My swift 5 codes

```
if let json = response.result.value {
                    print(json)
                         if let dictionaryArray = json as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject?> {
                             print(dictionaryArray)
                             let json = dictionaryArray
                             if let type = json["type"] as? String,
                                let results = json["data"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>> {
                                print(type)
                            for i in 0..<results.count{
                                    let json = results[i]
                                    if let id = json["id"] as? String, let jokeString = json["title"] as? String{
                                        self.items.append(Item(id: id, sectionId : "0", title: jokeString, detail:"", image: "", view : "0", status : "0"))
                                        print(json)

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

Any idea? Where have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root is an array  so its `[[String:Any]]`

```
 if let dictionaryArray = json as? [[String:Any]] {
```

Btw its better to use `Codable`

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: [:], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseData { res in
    guard let data = res.data else { return } 

      do {
         let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self, from:data)
         print(res)
      } 
      catch {
         print(error)
     }
}
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let type: String
    let data: [Datum]
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct Datum: Codable {
    let id, sectionID, title, detail: String
    let image, view, status: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case sectionID = "sectionId"
        case title, detail, image, view, status
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

```
if let dictionaryArray = json as? [[String:Any?]] {
    for item in dictionaryArray {
        if let type = item["type"] as? String,let results = item["data"] as?  [[String:Any?]] {
            print(type)
            for json in results {
                 if let id = json["id"] as? String, let jokeString = json["title"] as? String {
                    self.items.append(Item(id: id, sectionId : "0", title: jokeString, detail:"", image: "", view : "0", status : "0"))
                    print(json)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: im trying 1 sec

Comment: says here : if let type = json["type"] as? String,,  Error : Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an argument of type 'String'

Comment: can you change my codes ? gives error when I change  if let dictionaryArray = json as? [[String:Any]] {